# Call Action Method from Kendo UI Grid Custom Button - MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, telerik-grid

We are implementing Kendo UI grid in ASP.Net MVC application with custom buttons in grid columns and also custom buttons in grid toolbar.

On click of button we need to invoke an actionmethod in controller. We don't want to fire a javascript method and do an ajax call to controller.

Instead of that is there any way to call the actionmethod directly on click of buttons and pass the grid model to the controller.

Please let us know how to invoke controller's action method on click of custom buttons (in columns and toolbar) directly with out calling javascript and pass the grid model to the controller.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that it is possible to do with just a regular button, BUT you can do it with the Kendo menu.

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        Customer c = new Customer();
        c.Customer_Name = "Stephen";
        return View(c);
    }

    public ActionResult Redirect(Customer customer)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<YourProject.Models.Customer>()
    .Name("grid")
    .ToolBar(toolbar =>
    {
        toolbar.Template(@<text>
            <div class="toolbar">
                @(Html.Kendo().Menu().Name("menu").Items(items => items.Add().Text("Redirect").Action("Redirect", "Home", @Model)))
            </div>
        </text>);
    })
)
```

Hope that helps!